# How do I make a new array containing just one instance of duplicates from 2 separate arrays while combining them in php?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

So far I have done the following:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$duplicates = array_intersect($row, $row2);
```

How do I combine the 2 arrays and make a new one that just contains one instance of the previously repeated variables? (so if array $row contained the variable 'apple' 2 times and the array $row2 contained the variable 'apple' 3 times, in the new, merged array, 'apple' would only appear once.

edit: I didn't realize that the array_merge() function works differently for numbers than compared to strings. I gave the 'apple' example above but my arrays are dealing with product IDs which are numbers. PHP manual says

> If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not
>   overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

and I need help in merging arrays with numbers, what should I do?

Comment: I understand the question of how to combine two arrays (array_merge is the answer), but what do you mean "make a new one containing just one of the previously repeated values?"

Comment: Yes - this is a little unclear, what's in your arrays and what duplicate values don't you want?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Maybe this is totally wrong, but if you're grabbing ids from a MySQL database, aren't they going to be strings by default?

Comment: are they? I created the column as an INT value so I was assuming it was an integer, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

if you want to remove duplicate values after the merge then use array_unique();

so...

```
$c = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));
```

Comment: I took a look at php manual and it says duplicate values will not be overwrited if it's a numerical entry. Could you give me a suggestion for how to do this with a numerical entry? I'm dealing mainly with product IDs.

Comment: should I just convert my numerical values to strings so I can use array_merge() or is there another function I should be looking at?